How to set the value of a vaadin select with Typesript?
I have a form and after I submit the data I want to reset the data to the original state. But I don't find any specific function to do that.
select?.value = "asdf"; // not allowed
select?.setAttribute("value", value); // only works once

Is there a trick with that I can set the value with Typescript?

To reset a select element's value in TypeScript, you can use HTMLSelectElement type casting:
const select = document.querySelector('select') as HTMLSelectElement;
select.value = "default"; // This will work

Or if you're using optional chaining:
(select as HTMLSelectElement)?.value = "default";

This is the most straightforward and reliable way to set select values in TypeScript. The key is proper type casting to HTMLSelectElement.

Thank you. My problem was that I had a class member variable for the select and then I got the "left-hand side exception".
"(document.getElementById('id') as Select).value = defaultValue;" works now fine.
